# MVVMLight Message firing multiple times in WP7 app

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I am new to MVVMLight and have started to use it in my WP7 app. I have a View/page which registers for MessageDialogs and then my VM sends the message to show it. This works great. However, when you go back to the previous screen (with WP7 back button) and then enter the page again (using AppBar menu item) then the message fires twice (and increments every time you view the page). I assume it the View is registering every time and old versions are subscribing to the message, but I am not sure of how it should work.

I tried to call VM.Cleanup in my NavigatedFrom event to ensure the old messages are unregistered when they leave the page, but this did not help. Here is my code:

View:

```
public AboutPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Messenger.Default.Register<DialogMessage>(this, msg => { var result = MessageBox.Show(msg.Content, msg.Caption, msg.Button); });
}

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs args)
    {
        ViewModelLocator.AboutViewModelStatic.Cleanup();
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(args);
    }
```

AboutViewModel:  (Code gets fired by a command)

```
        var message = new DialogMessage("Why does this fire multiple times?", DialogMessageCallback) { Button = MessageBoxButton.OK, Caption = "" };
        Messenger.Default.Send(message);
```

That's all there is too it, but each time you come to this page it fires once more... I assume it is something to do with Cleanup but I am not sure how it is supposed to work in WP7...  any tips appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view is created & destroyed as you navigate through the application. Therefore, in your AboutPage view's constructor, the view is registering for the message every time it is created.

A better approach is to setup the registration in the ViewModel's constructor, use a ViewModelLocator and databind the View to the ViewModel. The ViewModel is created once and used throughout the lifetime of the application. [Jonas Follesoe's FlightsNorway](http://github.com/follesoe/FlightsNorway) is good WP7 application to learn about MVVMLight, you can find the MVVMLight Messenger class being used very nicely.

HTH, indyfromoz

Comment: hi indyfromoz - thanks, I have downloaded the source and checking it out - however, I thought for dialogs the View was a better place to handle the registering/showing of it - the VM just lets the V know when to show it? Even if the View in my example IS getting destroyed and created each time - should the old message listeners not be destroyed with the View? I am using the ViewModel + VMLocator method and the way of raising dialogs in your view like the MVVMLight sample - http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/resources/Samples/DialogMessageSample.zip. This sample is not for WP7 pages though.

Comment: I am afraid I haven't dug deep into the MVVMLight library's source code, therefore, I can't comment any further, sorry. I have a feeling that the messenger keeps a reference for every listener that registers for the messages.